# How to launch external tool from custom menu?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Can I run external program programmatically in Eclipse without configuring as an external tool through Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

External tools configuration is just another type of launch configuration.
The id is: **`org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ProgramLaunchConfigurationType`**, as used in [`org.eclipse.ui.externaltools/plugin.xml`](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewsvn/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.ui.externaltools/plugin.xml?view=co&revision=1.130&content-type=text/plain&pathrev=v20090428).
It is declared in [`org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.internal.model.IExternalToolConstants`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/externaltools/internal/model/IExternalToolConstants.java.htm#ixzz1GAbeinGL)

You can programmatically create a launch configuration, launch it and after the termination of the launch, you can delete it, so that it won't appear in the menu.

See the corner articles:

- [We Have Lift-off: The Launching Framework in Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html)
- [Launching Java Applications Programmatically](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Java-launch/launching-java.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of:

- that menu (Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration) has been criticized before ([bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27450))
- [The usual suggestion](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg05893.html) is to define a key to the command "Run Last Launched External Tool".
  But that isn't exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I am trying to add a menu option that may launch external tool dynamically without creating it in Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration. My best friend google didn't help me yet. Any Idea?